# CSS Left position scales image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Oddly enough I cannot get the problem to be reproducable here however in my own project switching from an svg to a png seems to have fixed the issue,  I had wanted to use an svg so that's a little inconvenient but not a huge thing overall.

I've been trying to get a draggable map and I've started messing around first with an svg image that is draggable and then cutoff by a div. My HTML looks like this

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("map"));    

function dragElement(el) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(el.id + "header")) {
    // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(el.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
    el.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    el.style.top = (el.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    el.style.left = (el.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div id="content" style=" width: auto; height: 100%; padding:5px 100px;"></div>
<div id="mapContainer" style="height: 500px; width: auto; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <img id="map" draggable="false" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/12/54/world-map-146505_1280.png" style="position:absolute;"></img>
</div>
<
```

And I'm using some js from w3 to do the dragging:
The problem is I need position absolute on the image to move it but that renders the overflow hidden of it's parent div null and void so I have to set the parent div to relative but when I do that the y axis works perfectly but the x axis (left) scales the image? Is there a way to fix this? Or perhaps I should approach this in an entirely different way?

Comment: Could you put up a minimal reproducible example so we can see the scaling effect? Also, is there a reason for the container to have width auto but height specified?

Comment: Yep! I'll edit the question to include that. I suppose the div does not need to have width auto necessarily. The height was specified to shorten the map box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet.js (https://leafletjs.com/) is the best tool to use for what I'm trying to achieve.